# Input type "date" isn't an editable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I create a context menu item with context type `"editable"`, it shows up when a context menu is opened on an `<input>` tag.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    ...
    contexts: ["editable"]
    ...
});
```

It works when the `<input>` is a normal textbox, however when it has a type such as `date` or `time`, the menu no longer shows up:

```
<input type="date">    <!-- Nope -->
```

Why is that and is there a way to make it appear (only on editable elements including different types of `<input>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/layout/HitTestResult.cpp?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1469877487&l=400) only non-readonly, non-disabled text input elements are `"editable"`.

Solution: change the context menu item's `context` dynamically.

Declare a content script for all/specified urls with mouse/keyboard event handler that checks the focused element and sends a message to the background script to [update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-update) the context menu item's `context` to `"page"` or `"editable"` accordingly.

- manifest.json:

  ```
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  ```
- content.js:

  ```
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', toggleContextMenu);
  window.addEventListener('keydown', toggleContextMenu);

  function toggleContextMenu(e) {

      if (e.button == 2 ||
          // "Apps Menu" key
          e.keyCode == 93 && !e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey) {

          var tag = e.target.localName;
          var type = e.target.type;

          var forceMenu =
              tag == 'input' && /^(date|time|month|color)$/.test(type) ||
              tag == 'select';

          chrome.runtime.sendMessage(forceMenu ? 'page' : 'editable');
      }
  }
  ```
- background.js:

  ```
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
      id: 'hello',
      title: 'Hello',
      contexts: ['editable']
  }, function() {
      var ignoreErrors = chrome.runtime.lastError;
  });

  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
      if (info.menuItemId == 'hello') {
          console.log('Hello');
      }
  });

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      chrome.contextMenus.update('hello', {contexts: [msg]});
  });
  ```

Comment: I assume that using a content script might be the only solution, however I only declared the "activeTab" permission so this is probably not suitable. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, there's no room for any other solution, unfortunately. You may submit a feature request on https://bugs.chromium.org

Comment: Or simply show it both in editable and page contexts. It's less elegant visually, but `"activeTab"`-only permission set is worth it.